# I need remedy of this error: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Server code node.js, express app

```js
app.put('/items/:id', async(req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id, 'came from id=> app.put');
  const qty = req.body;
  console.log(qty, 'came from quantity=> app.put');
  const filter = {
    _id: ObjectId(id)
  };
  console.log(filter, 'came from filter=> app.put')
  const options = {
    upsert: true
  };
  console.log(options, 'came from options=> app.put')
  const updatedDoc = {
    $set: {
      qty: qty,
    }

  }
  console.log(updatedDoc, 'came from updateddoc=> app.put')
  const result = await userItems.updateOne(filter, updatedDoc, options);
  console.log(result, 'came from result=> app.put')
  res.send(result);
})
```

Client side code

```js
const handleQuantity = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const qty = event.target.qty.value;
  console.log(qty);
  const url = `http://localhost:4000/items/${id}`
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        qty: qty
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);

    });
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> port 4000 [object Object] came from id=> app.put { qty: '5' } came
> from quantity=> app.put D:\web
> development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41
> var _this = _super.call(this, message) || this;
> ^
>
> BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a
> string of 24 hex characters or an integer
> at new BSONTypeError (D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
> at new ObjectId (D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:66:23)
> at ObjectId (D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:26:20)
> at D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\index.js:73:27
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
> at Route.dispatch (D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
> at param (D:\web development\warehouse-management-server-side-pippal5536\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for what caused the error, it's because the `id` passed to `ObjectID()` is invalid.